# Bootstrap 3 - Accordion effect breaks when using toggle methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap 3 Collapse Accordion Example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion).
I've noticed that when using the javascript `.collapse()` methods, the *accordion* effect seems to be acting unexpected.
See this [simple jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/21/).

Here I'm using `$('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');`. Why? Because to demonstrate the following behavior:

- Initially because of this piece of JavaScript, **panel #1** gets expanded.
- Clicking on **panel #2** gives us the accordion effect as one would expect.
- Clicking back on **panel #1** gives an *unexpected behavior* in that both panels now are expanded.

Now if you **remove** the javascript and execute the following steps:

- Click on **panel #1** to expand
- Click on **panel #2** to get the *accordion effect*.
- Clicking on **panel #1** again, still gives us the *accordion effect*.

The *observation* here is that when using the `.collapse('toggle')` method, the *accordion effect* seems to be broken?

Would one expect this to break or might this be a bug?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error? There is no error. I'm just getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: Add your `jquery.min.js` after `bootstrap.min.js`. This will solve the issue.fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/8/ @QuantumHive

Comment: @AakashThakur that would result in this error: `JavaScript runtime error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`.

Comment: You can remove your jQuery code and it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/11/  @QuantumHive

Comment: @AakashThakur I know, that's what I've mentioned and that's what I'm trying to describe: that this is an issue. I quote: "*When removing the javascript, the issues doesn't seem to arise.*".

Comment: There is no bug as such. Because you are adding `in` class to `collpaseOne`, thats why it is showing such behaviour. Checkout this fiddle and it will solve the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/14/  @quantum

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124983/discussion-between-quantumhive-and-aakash-thakur).

Comment: IMHO this question is not duplcated and there is no a correct answer. Solution is in [this post](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16360#issuecomment-96271746) and **fixed jsfiddle** is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gpcaretti/mypxn5tc/1/)

Answer (score 3):

> No there isn't any **bug** because in **JavaScript** you are toggling the collapse panels which removes the `in` class which actually opens the collapse panel.And i guess there comes the problem.

So, just remove `in` class from `#collapseOne` everything will work normal with that piece of your **JavaScript** code.

Hope it solves your issue.

Here is **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/4/)**

**=EDIT=**

Yes, it is a bug!
Solution is in [this post](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16360#issuecomment-96271746) and the **fixed jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gpcaretti/mypxn5tc/1/)**.

Comment: If I replace the javascript with `$('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');`, then the issue still seems to arise when repeating the steps provided in my question. I've adjusted the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7j58rj1/9/) to prove that.

Comment: The issue I'm trying to describe is, that after you're using one of the javascript methods, this seems to break the clicking functionality (e.g. the clicking behavior differs in the case that you would **not** use any javascript to toggle).